# calculating time execution for both device and host for CUDA programming

Tags: c++, time, cuda

i need to calculate the GPU run time code, and also the total running code (both host and device).
in my code i have two gpu kernel running, and in between a host for loop to copy data, below example can show what my code looks like

```
cuda event start

//FIRST kernel code call <<...>>

// cuda memory copy result back from device to host

CudadeviceSyncronize()

// copy host data to host array (CPU funtion loop)

// cuda memory copy from host to device

// SECOND Kernel call <<...>>

cuda event stop

//memory copy back from device to host
```

what i know is that i use events to calculate the kernel, Events precisely measure the actual time taken on the GPU for a kernel. so my question & goal is :

1- is my way i put the event calling above shown : will be recording the kernel Only and neglecting the host functions ?

2- will the host loop call affect the cuda events timing?

3- my goal is to calculate the GPU only , and also GPU+CPU together, the above will it achieve it or should i use clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, timer) to calculate the host ?

Answer (score 2):

A sequence like this:

```
float et;
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start);
kernel1<<<...>>>(...);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
host_code_routine(...);
kernel2<<<...>>>(...);
cudaEventRecord(stop);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);
```

will return, in `et`, the floating-point elapsed time (in milliseconds) that is (approximately) the *sum* of:

1. `kernel1` execution time
2. the (host) execution time associated with `host_code_routine`
3. `kernel2` execution time

If you wish to produce the sum of only 1 and 3 above, you will need to bracket each kernel (only) with a cudaEvent timing sequence, and then manually sum the two values in host code.

To answer your questions, then:

> 1- is my way i put the event calling above shown : will be recording the kernel Only and neglecting the host functions ?

No, the recording you have depicted will capture both host and device elapsed time in the sequence.

> 2- will the host loop call affect the cuda events timing?

Yes

> 3- my goal is to calculate the GPU only , and also GPU+CPU together, the above will it achieve it or should i use clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, timer) to calculate the host ?

If you want individual times and various sums, I suggest you time the kernels independently, and use some host-based method of timing the host code, and then combine the various components in whichever way you wish.

Comment: I re-run my tests and agree with this answer. Sorry for the firedrill. +1

Comment: @MarcoA. and Robert ,... Many thanks for the reply very clear!!!. if i may one last point  : it was recommended that i run the kernel in for loop (like 10 times for ex. ) to get exact time for the kernel run time.
this case will the floating-point elapsed time (in milliseconds) can be taken the same ? or should i divide it by the number or runs "PER KERNEL" ? (if i want to calculate it all with the host and gpu (becoz i have two kernels , each 10 times running, so , is it safe to say et / (10 + 10) ?

Comment: If you use the individual kernel timing as I suggested in my answer, you could modify the timing code to capture an array of times, each representing the time taken by that kernel in a given loop iteration.  You can then use this array to compute whatever statistics you need: the average, the maximum, the minimum, etc.  If you still need help, I suggest asking a new question.  It's not possible to give a complete answer here in the comments.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks will ask this on a new question